# Read a PDF on Android 10

Tags: java, android, file, file-access, android-10.0

Need to read a PDF on Android 10
The following code works fine on Android 9.0 but on Android 10 the application responsable for show the PDF just blink and return to my application.

```
            File pdfFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "Pdf");
            pdfFile.setReadable(true);
            if (pdfFile.exists()) {
                if (pdfFile.canRead()) {
                    if (pdfFile.canWrite()) {
                        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
                        Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        objIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                        objIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                        startActivityForResult(objIntent, req_code);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not writable! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not readable! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The file does not exists! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

On the method onActivityResult I'm receiving RESULT_CANCELED as result_code and data == null.

Comment: It is strange that your code works on Android 9 as also then you have to use a FileProvider to serve your file.

Comment: `"Pdf"` Pretty strange filename by the way.

Comment: Both on 9 and 10 this code should provoke a FileUriExposedException.

Comment: I think the main issue is `File pdfFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "Pdf");` to avoid all file storage issue add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` inside **Application** tag in your **AndroidManifest** file

Answer (score 1):

> The following code works fine on Android 9.0

Somebody on your project did something unfortunate to allow that code to work on Android 9. It should have failed three years ago, starting with Android 7.0, with a `FileUriExposedException`.

On Android 10, apps do not have access to external storage, except for a few limited app-specific locations. This is what Google was warning about starting with Android 7.0, that you should not use `Uri.fromFile()` anymore.

The right solution three years ago — and the right solution today — is to [use `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) to make that PDF available to the PDF viewer app.

See also:

- https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing
- https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file

Comment: Need something for Android 10 too.

Comment: @NarendraSingh: The answer covers Android 10.